# Как анимировать ввод кода?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

Есть `<textarea id="code"></textarea>`

Как анимировать ввод кода для codemirror?

```
<script>    
var delay;
      // Initialize CodeMirror editor with a nice html5 canvas demo.
      var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('code'), {
        mode: 'text/html',
        theme: "material",
        lineNumbers: true,
        viewportMargin: Infinity,
        styleActiveLine: true,
        tabMode: 'indent',
        matchBrackets: true,
        lineWrapping: true
      });
</script>
```

Что должно быть в `editor.setValue(/*Что тут?*/);`, чтобы код появлялся с анимацией по аналогии с [этим примером](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgKXRq)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хочу отметить, что в приведенном примере уже была реализованная функция.
Я использую ее ниже с пояснениями.

Сама идея проста как три копейки: нужно каждый определенный промежуток времени добавлять в редактор по 1 символу из исходного текста, пока таким образом не будет добавлен весь текст.

```js
// Задержка анимации в миллисекундах
var delay = 90;

// Initialize CodeMirror editor with a nice html5 canvas demo.
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('code'), {
  mode: 'text/html',
  theme: "material",
  lineNumbers: true,
  viewportMargin: Infinity,
  styleActiveLine: true,
  tabMode: 'indent',
  matchBrackets: true,
  lineWrapping: true
});

// Сколько символов уже обработано
var count = 0;
// Пример текста для анимации
var text = '<p>Просто пример анимации кода</p>'

// Устанавливаем таймер на повторение с указанной задержкой
var w = setInterval(function() {
  // Если обработан весь текст, удаляем таймер
  if (count == text.length) {
    clearInterval(w);
    return;
  }
  // Добавляем в редактор по 1 символу за раз 
  editor.setValue(editor.getValue() + text.charAt(count));
  // Увеличиваем счетчик обработанных символов из текста
  count++;
}, delay);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.11.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.11.0/mode/xml/xml.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.11.0/codemirror.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.11.0/theme/material.min.css">
<textarea id="code"></textarea>
```

`editor.getValue()` - получаем текущий текст из редактора
`text.charAt(count)` - получаем символ с порядковым номером `count` из исходного текста

Иными словами

```
editor.setValue(editor.getValue() + text.charAt(count));
```

Можно прочитать, как: "Назначить в качестве нового значения редактору предыдущее значение редактора плюс один символ из текста".

Comment: Большое спасибо)
Очень помогли

Comment: Не могли бы еще маленький нюанс подсказать ?
Дело в том что когда я стандартным методом "codemirror" вывожу код в iframe то происходят постоянные блики и в общем выглядит не очень.
как сделать вывод кода в iframe более плавным ("уменьшение delay не помогает").
пробую через .append, но выводит по одному символу.

Comment: Вот такая ерунда получается https://jsfiddle.net/x69waxjv/1/

Comment: Ну, во-первых, textarea не позволяет внутри себя подобную разметку. Во-вторых, я не наблюдаю бликов при анимации на указанном примере. В каком браузере наблюдаются проблемы? Обратите внимание, что вы перезаписываете `delay` внутри события `change`. Назовите переменную иначе.

Comment: Переменную изменил но все также.
Слева возле надписи "Таблица размеров обуви" бликает  "<"

Comment: Дело в том, что вы не дожидаетесь завершения написания разметки и в вывод попадает **неполная** разметка. В том числе незакрытые и неполные теги. Например, `<tr`. С точки зрения html это просто текст. Он и попадает в вывод, создавая "блик". Учтите, что хотя браузер и пытается корректно закрыть непарные теги, он не всегда делает это правильно. Для вывода превью нужно полностью менять подход.

Comment: Не подскажите в какую сторону думать?

Comment: Когда я подберу подходящий пример, я отвечу на другой ваш вопрос. На текущий вопрос мой код отвечает сполна, а менять суть вопроса будет неправильно.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо)